# Writing data to Android Bluetooth output stream throws: IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I have an Android Bluetooth application which manages a couple of remote devices(**Capsules**).

**Writing** data to the socket output stream of a Capsule worked yesterday, and after medium scale refactoring to the Android application **only**, I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: attempt to unlock read lock, not locked by current thread.

**Here is the socket creation code:**

```
 public final void connectWithCapsule(Capsule capsule)
        throws Exception {
    BluetoothSocket socket = capsulesSockets.get(capsule);

    if (socket == null) {
        try {
            // Method m = capsule.getBT_Device().getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
            // socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(capsule.getBT_Device(), Integer.valueOf(17));
            socket = capsule.getBT_Device().createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logError("Error creating RFcomm socket", e);
            throw e;
        }
        capsulesSockets.put(capsule, socket);
    }

    try {
        socket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logError("Error connecting socket", e);
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            logError("Error closing socket", e1);
        }
        capsulesSockets.remove(capsule);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**and the model which manages the in/out streams:**

```
public final class KitBT_ConnectionModel {

private final OutputStream[] outputStreams;

private final InputStream[] inputStreams;

public KitBT_ConnectionModel(OutputStream[] outputStreams, InputStream[] inputStreams) {
    super();
    this.outputStreams = outputStreams;
    this.inputStreams = inputStreams;
}

public void transmitData(byte[] bs)
        throws IOException {
    for (OutputStream outputStream : outputStreams) {
        outputStream.write(bs); // THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}

public InputStream[] getInputStreams() {
    return inputStreams;
}
}
```

**Note:** I do not perform any action with both of the streams, and the first write causes the exception.

First thing that pops to mind is which thread puts the read lock and when?

I've tried to play around with the threads which call the socket creation, and the streams transactions, I've made **sure**, 100% **sure** they have both been accessed by the **same** thread (and also tried accessing with different threads), but this exception persists.

Please enlighten me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa.........

Darn this LG phones!!!!

I gave the phone a hard reboot, removed the battery and started it over, and it works again...

turning the Bluetooth off and on didn't do the trick! I've been doing it for the past day or so.

God damn it nearly 24 hours of waste for nothing....

How messed up can these products be!

at least it works now!

Comment: Hey! I'm having a similar problem with an LG phone too, in which model did you had this problem?

Comment: Yikes, that is scary.  I feel for the end users with this phone who will have no idea why their Bluetooth is wonky.